# Не отрабатывают скрипты jQueryГлавные вкладки

Tags: jquery, drupal

Приветствую. Возникла следующая проблема:
Есть форма быстрого заказа, открывается в colorbox-node, создана на webform
Через jQuery навесил на сабмит цель яндекс метрики:

```
$("#webform-client-form-6 .webform-submit").click(function() {
                        yaCounter46054863.reachGoal('fastOrderSend'); return true;
                        setTimeout(function () {
                                window.location.replace("https://xn--80aaak5agq.xn--p1ai");     
                        }, 1000);

                });
```

Цель отрабатывает, однако перестало всплывать сообщение об отправке формы, само письмо отправляется корректно. Так же изначально не работает редирект после отправки
Добавил после onClick редирект на главную, но он так же не отрабатывает.
Подскажите пожалуйста - в чем тут у меня ошибка?

В целом код скрипта вот такого вида:

```
(function ($, Drupal, window, document) {
  'use strict';

  // To understand behaviors, see https://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors
  Drupal.behaviors.my_custom_behavior = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

          $('.form-number').once(function () {
            $('.form-number').before('<span class="minus-button"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></span>');
          });
          $('.form-number').once(function () {
            $('.form-number').after('<span class="plus-button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>');
          });



            $('.fa-minus').once(function () {
                $('.fa-minus').click(function() {
                    var formInt = parseInt($('#edit-submitted-count').val());
                    if (formInt > 1) {
                        formInt -=1;
                        $('#edit-submitted-count').val(formInt);
                    }
                });
            });


        $('.fa-plus').once(function () {
            $('.fa-plus').click(function() {
                var formInt = parseInt($('#edit-submitted-count').val());
                formInt +=1;
                $('#edit-submitted-count').val(formInt);
            });
        });

        $(".form-link").click(function() {
            yaCounter46054863.reachGoal('fullOrderOpen'); return true;
        });
        $(".fast-order").click(function() {
            yaCounter46054863.reachGoal('fastOrderOpen'); return true;
        });
        $("#webform-client-form-6 .webform-submit").click(function() {
            yaCounter46054863.reachGoal('fastOrderSend'); return true;
            window.location.replace("https://xn--80aaak5agq.xn--p1ai");






        });
        $("#webform-client-form-33 .webform-submit").click(function() {
            yaCounter46054863.reachGoal('fullOrderSend'); return true;
        });

    }
 };

})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```

Comment: хак (function($) {}(jQuery)); применяли? кстати yaCounter46054863.reachGoal() можно навесить и в исходном коде хтмл, почему решили отдельно?

Comment: хм, а можно поподробнее про хак? Сделал так потому что сама форма формируется модулем, его соответственно не вариант изменять.

Comment: тут гляньте http://amiweb.ru/drupal-jquery/kak-podruzhit-drupal-i-jquery

Comment: Ну в принципе примерно так и делаю, остальной то код работает, даже цель отрабатывает... А вот именно редирект нет.

Comment: Может проблема в том, что у вас `return true` до вашего редиректа происходит? Оно ведь по идее до вашего `setTimeout` даже не доходит

Comment: Тоже так думал, даже менял местами, по идее она же выходит из функции при return, но все равно не заработало.

Comment: Может проблема с `location.replace`? Почему не используете `window.location.href = 'myurl.com/main_page'`?

Comment: И работу вы тестите локально, или сразу деплой делаете? Возможно, у вас скрипты закешировались(друпал мощно кеширует), попробуйте почистить кеш браузера и поставить ваш редирект раньше ретурна

Comment: Да, кэш чищу всегда, я через Ctrl +F5 перезагркужаю, попробовал поменял местами, почистил кэш и браузера и друпал - не работает. Прям странно. А может быть проблема в модальном окне? Оно ведь закрывается при отправке формы, может скрипт не отрабатывает дальше ? Хотя та же цель к примеру отрабатывает то корректно. location.replace использовал так как это первое что нашел, несколько дней только jQuery изучаю)

Comment: Странно - если пишу например такwindow.location.href = 'https://xn--80aaak5agq.xn--p1ai';
     alert('test'); 
      yaCounter46054863.reachGoal('fastOrderSend'); return true; , то алерт отрабатывает. Получается проблема в редиректе?

Comment: пробуйте так с протоколом `window.location.href = 'https://xn--80aaak5agq.xn--p1ai'`, а адрес `xn--80aaak5agq.xn--p1ai` браузер видимо видит как относительный от страницы вашего сайта `ваш.сайт/страница_формы/xn--80aaak5agq.xn--p1ai`

Comment: Не совсем понял, Вы об этом?window.location.href = 'https://xn--80aaak5agq.xn--p1ai';
      alert('test'); 
       yaCounter46054863.reachGoal('fastOrderSend'); return true;  У меня сейчас через эту функцию и написано, не работает хоть убей, алерт отрабатывает корректно, цель тоже, прям странно, что то мешает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос с помощью Rules https://m5-web.com/blog/138
Все работает отлично, переадресация с помощью скрипта так и не заработала.